# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve - The type or namespace name 'HttpWebRequest' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am implementing Web Request for WSDL in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Application.

The code is as shown below:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var httpContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

    return httpResponse;
}

public static Task<string> SendSoapWebRequest(string url, string action, string xmlString)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string soapEnvelopeXml = xmlString;
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(url, action);

    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(string soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soapEnvelopeXml));
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpWebRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Then **HttpWebRequest** is highlighted in:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(url, action);
```

and

```
private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(string soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
```

Then **WebResponse** is highlighted in

```
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpWebRequest` is in the `System.Net` namespace. You are missing a `using System.Net;` at the top of your code, so the compiler won't be able to find it, hence the "Are you missing a using directive" message in the error message.

If it still complains after this:

`HttpWebRequest` is part of the `System.Net.Requests.dll` assembly, so you should install the `System.Net.Requests` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests), hence the "Are you missing an assembly reference" in the error message.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-6.0